# Java generics TypeReference for collection method not working

Tags: java, generics

I have three classes in play here:

```
public class MyClass1<T, ID> {

  @Getter
  private static class IdHolder<ID> {
    private ID id;
  }
}

public class MyClass2<T> {
   public MyClass2(Class<? extends T> type) {
   }

   public List<T> fetch() {
   }
}
```

Inside of `MyClass1`, I need to create an instance of `MyClass2` and call the `fetch()` method:

```
List<IdHolder<ID>> previous = new MyClass2<IdHolder<ID>>(???).fetch();
```

If I use **raw types** like this:

```
List<IdHolder> previous = new MyClass2<>(IdHolder.class).fetch();
```

It does work, but then IntelliJ complains about me using raw types (obviously).

I have tried:

```
TypeReference<IdHolder<ID>> t = new TypeReference<IdHolder<ID>>() {};
```

What can I put in `???` to get the class type for `IdHolder<ID>` or is that just not possible due to type erasure and I have to use raw types? I thought that was the whole point of `TypeReference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is that just not possible due to type erasure and I have to use raw types?

That's correct, it is not possible.  You will have to use raw types.